# FFmpeg api, how to mux raw h264 without pts timestamps to mp4 or m3u8

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I tried to follow the following example: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/muxing.c

**Problem:** my stream h264 is not possible to do demux, so the frames I send to the encoder have some blank data, example `pkt.pts == AV_NOPTS_VALUE`, this causes an error when calling the `av_interleaved_write_frame` (mux) function.

Considering that the framerate is not constant, how do I generate the `pkt.pts` correctly from the video frames as I get it from the raw live stream?

Is there any way for ffmpeg libav to automatically calculate `pkt.pts`, `pkt.dts` timestamps as I send frames to the muxer with `av_interleaved_write_frame`?

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question, but it's still worth answering, since FFMPEG doesn't make it easy.

Consequent frames' PTS and DTS (in generic case they would be the same) shall be equal to `previousPacketPTS + curtrentPacket.duration`. Your `curtrentPacket.duration` is just what it sounds - information of how long given frame would be displayed before switching to the next one. Remember that this duration is in stream's time base units, which is rational of a second (for example 1/50 time base means the shortest frame of that stream can last 1/50 sec, or 20 ms). So you can translate time difference between two video frames into video frame duration, ie. when you receive a video frame, then it's duration would be the time needed for the next frame to come - again, in stream's time base. And that's all you need for calculating PTS and DTS for the frames.